# Bootstrap horizontal drop down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Take a look at this picture:

[image: example]

I want the dropdown menu items to be stack from left to right (horizontally).
I cannot seem get this to work, tried using "list-inline" class mentioned in the 
official documentation, that only makes things worse.

Here's the HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">List Item</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" id="">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="">6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 15):

Enclose those **`li`** into a **`ul`** list and the class as **`list-inline`** like this

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <ul class='list-inline'>
                    <li><a href="#" id="">1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="">2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="">3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="">4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="">5</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
</ul>
```

Check this **screenshot**

[image]

Here is the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BjtNY/289/)

**Updates1:**

As I mentioned in comments, `class: dropdown-menu` has the **`min-width as 160px`**.  Hence it is fixed to width.  Try to override it.

[image]

**Updates2:**

As I mentioned in comments, bootstrap has some default style which can be overridden like

```
.dropdown-menu{
min-width: 200px;
}
```

Incase if you feel that it affects other elements then override using `id` selector.

```
#Numberlist.dropdown-menu{
min-width: 200px;
}
```

Find the difference in this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BjtNY/291/)

Comment: @elad.chen It seems `list-inline` has some specific width.  Let me check it.

Comment: Thanks, I'd like that

Comment: Changing the min-width does not help. Plus dropdown-menu needs to expand based on content.

Comment: @elad.chen Bootstrap have a default structure. So you can override as you need.  check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BjtNY/290/

Comment: @elad.chen I have updated my answer, if you get time check it.

Comment: setting the width of the container to a fixed width is not the desired behaviour. I want the container to expand based on the content. Is it possible when its position is absolute ?

Comment: @Praveen - works well for me, though the text color is now blue, not black. Any thoughts on how to fix that without overriding more css?

Answer (score 5):

the dropdown-menu is restricted by the width of it's li container.

just add :

```
.dropdown-menu {
    margin-right:-1000px;
}

.dropdown-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This was the easiest and cleanest solution that worked in all browsers.

Comment: not that it's high on my bucket list, but one day, hopefully not too far into the future - I'd really like to learn why this works…

Answer (score 3):

A full width - 100% menu width option should be possible

`.navbar-nav {position: relative; }`

`li.dropdown {position: static;}`

`.dropdown-menu {width: 100%;}`

`.dropdown-menu > li {display: inline-block;}`

or thereabout… the basic idea is to make the dropdown position relative to the menu and not the li… as migli rightly points out

> "the dropdown-menu is restricted by the width of it's li container."

Answer (score 1):

A combination of

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <ul class='list-inline'>
<!-- etc. -->
```

with

```
.dropdown-menu {
    margin-right:-1000px;
}
```

and some additional appearance styling worked for me.
Thanks!

Comment: The inner <ul> should be within a <li> i.e. <ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><ul class="list-inline"><!-- etc --></ul></li></ul>

Comment: @FullStack a <ul> cannot be a direct child of another <ul>. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html states that the permitted contents of <ul> are zero or more <li> items. You may find that your ever-so-helpful browser is inserting the missing elements around the inner <ul>

Answer (score 0):

To add to @dj.cowan's solution, I removed the .navbar-nav position property utilizing instead the default .navbar position, which then made the dropdown 100% width of the page. I then added float:right to the li to lineup under navbar-right.

`li.dropdown {position: static; float:right}`

`.dropdown-menu {width: 100%;}`

`.dropdown-menu > li {display: inline-block;}`