# Adding list in dropdown in inline boostrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some dropdown in bootstrap 3, that goes like this

```
<li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
 </li>
```

What i need is to display dropdown items all in inline, not one under other?
Is that possible easy in boostrap?

Comment: To make it a dropside overrite the related CSS

Comment: Just list in dropdown not to be in stacked, but inline?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap horizontal drop down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616040/bootstrap-horizontal-drop-down)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way just by css :

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/122671

**CSS** :

```
.dropdown.open ul{
      display:flex;
    }
```

**UPDATE** :

**Fiddle** : http://www.bootply.com/122681

**CSS**:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) 
{
  .dropdown.open ul{
      display:flex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, nice wokring like charms, teel me just i need to revert to original on smaller screen, how to do that?

Comment: Works like charm, txanks