# Inline / Side-by-side Bootstrap dropdown menus

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm looking to combine two dropdowns-style lists inline (side-by-side) on a button.

So, similar to the example at http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-single, but with **two** menus inline popping down.

I know bootstrap has a `list-inline` class (seen in action here: [Bootstrap horizontal drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616040/bootstrap-horizontal-drop-down)) but I want vertical lists next to one another, not all items horizontally.

What is the magical combination that will allow me to put these vertical lists next to each other in a dropdown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little more googling, found this article: http://www.devlifeline.com/2013/09/multi-column-bootstrap-dropdown.html

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Heading</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu multi-column">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span6">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Col 1 - Opt 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Col 1 - Opt 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="span6">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Col 2 - Opt 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Col 2 - Opt 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown-menu.multi-column {
    width: 400px;
}

.dropdown-menu.multi-column .dropdown-menu {
    display: block !important;
    position: static !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

**Live example:** http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/daeN

Comment: I really like this snippet, my challenge is to handle a menu that is database populated when the count of ul tags are unknown.