# About bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Bootstrap horizontal dropdown-menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985065/bootstrap-horizontal-dropdown-menu) has some sample codes to alter the bootstrap dropdown menu in to a horizontal one, but i'd like to keep both for special use.

The core of turning dropdown menu to horizontal menu is adding

```
.open> ul {
    display: inline-flex !important;
}
```

Therefore i tried to change it to

```
.open> ul.dropdown-menu-A {
    display: inline-flex !important;
}
```

So only the Ul tags having dropwdown-menu-A within would be horizontal.
 But unfortunately the above method do not solve my problem. It's still either all horizontal one or standard one.

Comment: can you please provide the example where you have you tried your code?

Comment: what do you mean by example? I just apply bootstrap in standard way

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/3CwzH/168/

I have found myself a solution, which is exactly like what i tired yesterday.

```
.open> ul {
    display: inline-flex !important;
}

.open> ul.dropdown-menu-A {
    display: inline-flex !important;
}
```