# How do I make the dropdown menus appear horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am currently learning to develop a website using HTML5, CSS, Bootstrap and JavaScript.
How do I display these buttons to be displayed horizontally instead of vertically? I want them to be displayed in the middle, below the Quick Buy with decent spacing between the buttons. [image: Click here for screenshot of the problem]

Here are some parts of my code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery and JS bundle w/ Popper.js -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<main class = container>
  <form action="" method="">
      <div class="container mt-5">
          <h3 class="text-center">Quick Buy</h3>
          <br>
          <div class="form-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Select Movie
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Disney's Mulan</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tenet</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Pinocchio</a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Select Cinema
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Yellow Dhoby</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Yellow Vivo City</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Yellow Bedok</a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Book Now</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </form>
</main>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap horizontal drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616040/bootstrap-horizontal-drop-down)

Comment: You can use flexbox or inline, but you better add your question with css rules.

Comment: This is even easier to do without Bootstrap: just set the `display: flex;` property on the parent

Comment: hi @vedsil, sorry it does not answer my question... i want the buttons themselves to be displayed horizontally, not the dropdown values

Comment: hi @sergeykuznetsov I'm sorry I did not rephrase my question clear enough. Actually, i want the buttons themselves to be displayed horizontally, not the dropdown values.

Comment: hi @expressjs123 I'm sorry I did not rephrase my question clear enough. Actually, i want the buttons themselves to be displayed horizontally, not the dropdown values.

Comment: @user14489561 Yes, so on `.container.mt-5` you can create the flexbox layout

Comment: @expressjs123 thank you for taking the time to answer this question. I did that method (.container mt-5 {
    flex-direction: row;
}) on my css file but to no avail...

Comment: First you have to put `display: flex;` on the parent before you can apply any other flexbox rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `d-inline` class in `form-group` div and `text-center` in `container` div

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery and JS bundle w/ Popper.js -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<main class = container>
  <form action="" method="">
      <div class="container mt-5 text-center">
          <h3 class="text-center">Quick Buy</h3>
          <br>
          <div class="form-group d-inline">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Select Movie
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Disney's Mulan</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tenet</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Pinocchio</a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group d-inline">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Select Cinema
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Yellow Dhoby</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Yellow Vivo City</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Yellow Bedok</a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group d-inline">
              <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Book Now</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </form>
</main>
```

Comment: hi, thank you for taking the time to answer my question. actually, I want these buttons to stretch out horizontally and not vertically.

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly the answer I was looking for, I just started learning web development this week so apologies for my weak skills. But thank you once again!

Answer (score 1):

Enclose those **`li`** into a **`ul`** list and the class as **`list-inline`** like this

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <ul class='list-inline'>
                    <li><a href="#" id="">1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="">2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="">3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="">4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="">5</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
</ul>
```

This will add dropdown horizontally as a list.
Bootstrap has some default style which can be overridden like

```
.dropdown-menu{
min-width: 200px;
}
```

Incase if you feel that it affects other elements then override using `id` selector. Put id="list1" to the div you want as dropdown.

```
#list1.dropdown-menu{
min-width: 200px;
}
```

Find the difference in this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BjtNY/291/)

Comment: hi sourabh potnis! thank you for taking the time to answer this question. I really appreciate it. However, I want the buttons themselves to be displayed horizontally, not the dropdown values.

Answer (score 0):

Add Style `style="display:inline"` in `form-group` div.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery and JS bundle w/ Popper.js -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<main class = container>
  <form action="" method="">
      <div class="container mt-5">
          <h3 class="text-center">Quick Buy</h3>
          <br>
          <div class="form-group" style="display:inline">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Select Movie
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Disney's Mulan</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tenet</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Pinocchio</a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" style="display:inline">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Select Cinema
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Yellow Dhoby</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Yellow Vivo City</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Yellow Bedok</a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" style="display:inline">
              <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Book Now</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </form>
</main>
```